# Google adds useless parameters to my URL

Tags: google, url, url-rewriting

I have recently added my website to Google, and I don't understand why he adds useless parameters to my URLs.

Normal URL:

```
build/view/2/akali/mid
```

Google URL:

```
build/view/2/akali/mid?role=adc
```

That's boring because the parameter `role` take the value `adc` instead of `mid`.

How can I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to change the option on Google Webmaster Tool (URL Parameters -> edit -> No URLs), don't forget to use [the canonical tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en) to help Google to erase the bad pages indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't add parameter to URL alone. Googlebot follows links and display URL it finds.

Search on your webpages and links from other websites. Then, correct these links if you don't want Google displays them.

Comment: All urls are correct on the website. Look at https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#q=site:top-builds.com&safe=off&ei=-_niUe-dA5GShgfHj4DYCw&start=40&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.d2k&fp=303b0adc67d3363b&ion=1&biw=1745&bih=879

Comment: Maybe you have backlinks with incorrect parameters. Look at your JavaScript code also. Remember Googlebot saves links it finds.

Comment: Checked all links, also in js scripts. No way. :(

Comment: Did you check links from external websites?

Comment: Yep, all websites have the main link without parameter.

Comment: Maybe a Googlebot bug but I'm sceptical. Google displays a link it found.

Comment: That's really annoying.

Comment: I think I have found the solution: Google Webmaster Tools -> URL Parameters -> edit -> No URLs.